# How would I call a function called list[] ,which takes a array of numbers and then using println to print the value of each element of the array

Tags: java, arrays

```
public void A10( String list[] )
```

the array list is what I'm trying to call to then I guess put `Int` values into it for each line of the array then using `Println` to then print the value of each part of the array on its own line.

But I don't know how I would go about doing that?

Comment: `public void ( String list[] )` is not valid Java code. Your question looks like a homework assignment. StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Your first resource to look at should be your instructor. They are there for you and want to have you follow a specific path to get to the endpoint of understanding. Please read the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)!

Comment: `String list[]` is the method argument. The code you posted is actually missing a method name and is therefor not valid java. It should be something like `public void someMethodName(String[] list)`

Comment: done ive added a method name

Answer (score 1):

First you would want to understand method declaration.

**public**(where the method can be called from)

**void**(What dataType will be returned)

**myStringPrinter** (name of method, you are missing this part)

**(String[] list)** (what dataType(s) does the method take in and declare a variable)

All together your method declaration should looks like this:

```
public void myStringPrinter (String[] list)
```

I want to make a note how to correctly declare a String array.

```
String[] list
```

The brackets [] declare that it's an array of said datatype. Without the brackets it's just a single value of said datatype.

```
String notList = "foo";
String[] list = {"foo", "bar"}
int oneNumber = 1;
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4}
```

Notice that the brackets [] are not needed on the variable name.

Now that we have your method declaration ironed out we can now do something inside the method.
To print each value of an array.
You would want to iterate through the array. You could use a for loop.
Declaring a forloop isn't the most intuitive thing. But once you understand what is going on in the parentheses, it makes sense.

```
public void myStringPrinter (String[] list) {
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("List value: " + list[i]);
    }
}
```

To start a for loop we have to iterate on something. So we create int i and make it 0.

**int i = 0**

Then we have to state a condition for the loop to continue.

**i < list.length**

i equals 0, and the list.length will equal the size of the array.

So we are saying. "While i is less than the array size"

finally after each iteration we will increment i.

**i++**

Now i will increment and we can use it to specify what value we want from the array.

**list[i]**

I hope this helps you understand.

Comment: thank you that works

Comment: Please remember to mark it as the answer and hit the up arrow so that others may more easily find information they are looking for.